# Cat all files and add a tag as the file name before a character

Tags: linux, awk, sed, cat

Hello everyone I have seevral files such as

```
FILE1
>content
AGGAGAjg
GAUGAUGUG
AAG
FILE2
>Againontent
HDHDIHD
DHHDDHK
DH
```

and I would like to cat all those files into one unique
using `cat FILE* >> Unique_file`

but also to add the name of the file just before the `>` in each file.

then the content of the `Unique_file` would be :

```
>FILE1_content
AGGAGAjg
GAUGAUGUG
AAG
>FILE2_Againontent
HDHDIHD
DHHDDHK
DH
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for file in $(ls FILE*); do echo $file >> unique_file; cat $file >> unique_file; done`

This will echo the file name and append it to the output file before appending the contents of the file itself.

Comment: Don't parse the output of ls. It is bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following. Written and tested in GNU `awk.

```
awk 'FNR==1{sub(/^>/,"&"FILENAME"_")} 1' file1 file2
```

***Explanation:*** Checking condition `FNR==1` which will be true for each file's first line. Then substituting starting > with > and current filename with adding a `_`  in current line. 1 will print all rest of the lines.

NOTE: You can pass multiple files to `awk`, its capable of reading multiple files by it.

Answer (score 1):

Looping on each file and using sed:

```
for fil in *;
do 
 sed "1s/>/>$fil\_/" $fil >> Unique_file;   # On the first line of the file substitute ">" for ">" followed by the file name (fil) and "_"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a combination of:

`cat /sharedpath/{unique1,unique2,unique3}/filename > newfile`

and

`tail -n +1 file1 file2`

into this:

`tail -n +1 /sharedpath/{folder1,folder2,...,folder_n}/file.extension | cat > /sharedpath/newfile`

The result is a **newfile** that contains the content from each subfolder (unique1,unique2..) in the {} brackets, separated by subfolder name.

***note unique1=folder1***

In my case the **file.extension has the same name** in all subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ grep . file*|sed -E 's/(^[^:]*):>/>\1_/; s/^[^:]*://'
>file1_content
AGGAGAjg
GAUGAUGUG
AAG
>file2_Againontent
HDHDIHD
DHHDDHK
DH
```